# How to write mouse wheel scroll event when wheel (middle) button held down?

Tags: vb.net

Can someone guide me to achieve this requirement in `vb.net`??
Algorithm:

```
If middle click pressed AND mouse wheel scroll up
number ++;
else
number--;
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
If e.Button = MouseButtons.Middle and e.Delta > 0
```

I wanted something like a combination of Mouse Down and Mouse Wheel events which detects both middle click and mouse wheel scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle more than one event. You need to capture the MouseWheel event and the MouseDown/MouseUP events.

```
Private mouseDown As Boolean = False
Private Sub Form1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel
    If e.Delta > 0 And mouseDown Then
        Console.WriteLine("Scrolling with button down")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Button Not down whilst scrolling")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Middle Then
        mouseDown = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Middle Then mouseDown = False
End Sub
```

Write to a private variable when the middle mouse is down, then run your condition statement within the wheel handler.